# How to map i-th elements of tuples in a list to keys in another list to form a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I would like to map i-th elements of tuples within given list to keys that are available in another list to form a dictionary.

Here below is the code I have (it is not working as it is updating the values so I end up with the latest value rather than what I am after):

```
k = [1,2,3]
v = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]

d = {}
for i, j in enumerate(k):
    if len(v) > 1:
        for k in range(len(v)):
            d[j] = v[k][i]
    else:
        d[j] = v[0][i]
print(d)
#{1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}
```

I would like to have this output instead:

```
{1: ('a', 'd'), 2: ('b', 'e'), 3: ('c', 'f')}
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `zip` with a `dict` comprehension

**Ex:**

```
k = [1,2,3]
v = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]

print({i: v for i, v in zip(k, zip(*v))})
#or
print(dict(zip(k, zip(*v))))
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ('a', 'd'), 2: ('b', 'e'), 3: ('c', 'f')}
```